# How do I send email via PHP from within an HTML file?

Tags: php, html, email

My website is HTML5.  Consequently, my files are `.html`.  I have a `contact.html` file that I would like to use to send a message from, using PHP.  I don't have much experience with PHP (so if anyone could recommend a better alternative, non-.NET way of sending email, please let me know).

My initial thought was to include my PHP code inside my HTML file (whether or not this is possible or even recommended, I don't know).  I've done this once before, and I believe I remember having a `form` tag that somewhere in its attributes specified the `.php` file that I used to send the email.

Something like `<form someattribute="sendmail.php"> ... </form>`.

**QUESTION**: Given what I **THINK** I should do (above), is this the best approach (specifying the PHP file inside my form tag), or do you recommend a better way to send email from a raw `.html` file?

Comment: the way you plan to do it is correct. Submit a form to a PhP script, treat the POST variables in that PhP script and send the mail, then redirect to a confirmation page.

Comment: The someattribute should be action='sendmail.php' and your on the right  track.

Comment: don't forget the action='post' attribute in your form.

Comment: @Mike Marks I suggest you look through the PHP manual on the `mail()` function. [**Click here**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do that only with HTML. If you stick to PHP solution, try

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['send'])) //check the submit button was pressed
    {
        //get variables from POST array. Remember we specified POST method
        $to = $_POST['to'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        //set up headers
        $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
                    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
                    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        //send the email and save the result
        $result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 

        //was it sent?
        if($result)
        {
            echo "Successfuly sent the email";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "An error has occured";
        }
    }
?>
<hr>
<form method="POST">
    To: <input type="text" name="to"> <br>
    Subject: <input type="text" name="subject"> <br>
    Text: <textarea name="message"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
</form>
```

You do not need to specify where the form points to because it is the same file. Otherwise it would be

```
<form action="somefile.php" method="POST">
```

Altough you have to specify the method POST, otherwise all the data will be sent through GET by default

PHP has a mail function that is used to send the email http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE
>   otherwise.

We check if the email is sent or not and print a corresponding message. Then, regardless of the result, we print out the message form.

Comment: If it the same file, then it is not needed. But thanks for pointing put, I edited the answer

Comment: Would I not have an "action" attribute that specifies my PHP script?

Comment: You guys are quick to comment.  HAHA.

Comment: @VladimirHraban Then you should make a note of it. It seems that the OP does not have the same amount of experience as you and I. (wink)

Comment: @MikeMarks Yes we are. All in the name of setting things straight, and to give you all the possible options available (wink)

Comment: @VladimirHraban I would also suggest that you include either a comment as to where to put the `mail()` function/directives, or even better put it in (wink) Unless the OP already knows how to; however it would be beneficial for others who may happen to fall on this question in order to seek answers. Cheers

Comment: @VladimirHraban You have no `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` etc. As per [**PHP manual on mail()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) - You have `echo "Successfuly sent the email";` that won't do anything except echo a message. *Just saying*

Comment: @Fred But it is on the 4th line of code :) In IF statement    if(mail($_POST['to'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message']))

Comment: @VladimirHraban Ok I agree. Yet what about first defining your variables such as `$to=$_POST['to];` and so on, or is there something I'm not getting? Plus no header information, could end up as Spam.

Comment: @VladimirHraban Ah yes, much much better. The OP will thank you for it. +1 coming right up, cheers

Comment: @MikeMarks Go ahead, you can use Vladimir's answer and accept it as the correct one, cheers. Just click that little checkmark over to the left and under the arrows.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily send the mail by posting the data into a php file. Just need to write some codein that php file and in form user **action='phpfilename.php'.** Thats it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to send the form info via e-mail it's fairly simple.

```
<form action="sendmail.php">
```

just need to make sure you're coding your php file correctly.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

mail.html

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
    To <input type="text" name="to"/><br/>
    Subject <input type="text" name="subject"/><br/>
    Message <textarea name="message"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

mail.php

```
<?php
    mail($_POST["to"] , $_POST["subject"], $_POST["message"]);
    header("Location: mail.html"); //redirect the user
?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't "method" be POST?

Comment: It can be whatever you would like. But I would recommend post. EDIT MADE.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is only client side, and is just markup so it cannot send an email. You should have a form that posts to a PHP page, as you suggest, and that PHP page sends the email.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp